# Selecting overlapping rectangles from a database table

Tags: postgresql, geometry, trigonometry

I have a database table (postgres) that stores rectangles, defined by the grid co-ordinates (X and Y) of the bottom left and top right hand corners. The table is defined something like this......

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
  minX             NUMERIC, 
  minY             NUMERIC, 
  maxX             NUMERIC,
  maxY             NUMERIC 
);
```

Where `minX` and `minY` are the co-ordinates of the bottom left corner, and `maxX` and `maxY` the co-ordinates of the top right.

I'm trying to come up with a SQL query that will pull back the records of any rectangle that overlaps a target rectangle also defined by the bottom left and top right corners - `minX_T`, `minY_T`, `maxX_T`, `maxY_T`.

This is what I've come up with so far...

```
SELECT * FROM tableA  
WHERE 
( 
  ( 
    (minY <=minY_T AND maxY >= minY_T) 
    AND 
    (minX <=minX_T AND maxX >= minX_T) 
  ) 
  OR 
  ( 
    (minY <=maxY_T AND maxY >= maxY_T) 
    AND 
    (minX <=maxX_T AND maxX >= maxX_T) 
  ) 
  OR 
  ( 
    (minY <=maxY_T AND maxY >= maxY_T) 
    AND 
    (minX <=minX_T AND maxX >= minX_T) 
  ) 
  OR 
  ( 
    (minY <=minY_T AND maxY >= minY_T) 
    AND 
    (minX <=maxX_T AND maxX >= maxX_T) 
  )
)
```

This works (partially) it selects any records from the database where a corner of the rectangle falls within the target, however it wont find all variations and it's a really messy bit of SQL. At first glance this is a really simple problem, but I've been racking my brains on this for hours now - each time a I think I have a solution I discover a scenario that it *won't* work for!

Any ideas?  (BTW - this only for rectangles with sides either horizontal, or vertical)

---

ok, after another few hours, this simpler version seems to do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE 
( 
 minX_T < maxX 
  AND 
 maxX_T > minX 
  AND 
 minY_T < maxY 
  AND 
 maxY_T > minY 
)
```

Comment: Normally I go right to the fully encompassed object and check it both ways (i.e. flip the object you're checking with the object you're checking against / flip `_T` with the non-`_T`).  I believe that's what you discovered and fixed in your update.  I think you're good to go from an accuracy standpoint, but I can't speak to optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel (or in this case the box). Postgres provides [geometric data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-geometric.html) (in this case point and box) and the necessary [geometric functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-geometry.html) for exactly what you want.  
 The following sql function will return any overlapping 'box' from your table:

```
create or replace 
function overlaps_rectangle( rectangle_in box) 
 returns setof tablea
 language sql
 as $$
    select * 
      from tablea 
     where box( point(maxx,maxy),point(minx,miny)) && rectangle_in ;
$$;
```

See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=51adc9512f164a1065c8a56bf34f8c1b):

The function is not actually needed, the sql statement itself can run as is as a script. I just find passing parameters to a function easier than modifying a script. Going a step further and depending on other uses you could actually store the values as Points or even Boxes. Samples include in above reference. Note: as a Box

> Any two opposite corners can be supplied on input, but the values will
> be reordered as needed to store the upper right and lower left
> corners, in that order.